# Exploratory factor analysis for clustered data in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am new to both R and factor analysis, and I need to run EFA for a dataset that used cluster survey design. Is there any package for FA in R that can handle cluster data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounting for survey clustering doesn't alter your parameter estimates, only the standard errors. EFA is a descriptive technique, which doesn't care about standard errors.

For the purpose of EFA, you can ignore the clusters.

Comment: Thanks indeed for the idea. Could you please also give any journal or book reference for it?

Comment: I don't know of one that links those two facts together. But you can confirm them separately yourself by running an analysis with clusters, and by doing a factor analysis and changing the sample size (but not the correlation matrix). If you are challenged, I would reverse it and ask the challenger why they think it matters.